# Multivariative, multi-step time series prediction with LSTM and TimeseriesGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I have a timeseries dataset which consists of 3 features - temperature, wind speed and atmospheric pressure. It was measured every 1 minute. I'm trying to predict future temperature based on the measurements from last 20 minutes.

```
Date                   temp    wind    pres
2020-01-01 00:00:00    13.67   12.1    1010
2020-01-01 00:01:00    13.51   12.0    1010
...
```

I was thinking about using LSTM in Keras. To predict multi step I read that it can be achieved by predicting one step ahead and then using predicted data to make new prediction.

If I understand it correctly it would work like this (let's say input's length is 3):
`[[a', a'', a'''], [b', b'', b'''], [c', c'', c''']]`
predicts `[d', d'', d''']`
and then I predict next step with previous prediction: `[[b', b'', b'''], [c', c'', c'''], [d', d'', d''']]`
and so on. The main flaw of this method is that prediction error will get bigger with every prediction.

I have a problem with choosing correct params for timeseries generator.
Length is 20 because I want to use last 20 steps (20 x 1min). If I want to predict next step I was thinking about using batch_size = 1 but it takes a lot longer than when I set it to, let's say, 5. Does the batch_size actually matter when it comes to accuracy?

```
gen = TimeseriesGenerator(x, x, length = 20, batch_size = batch_size)
```

as for the model itself:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(x, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(20, 3)))
model.add(LSTM(y))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.fit(gen, epochs = n)
```

Is this approach correct? My results are not very accurate to be honest.